# How do I remove McAfee Antivirus from Windows Home Server?

Tags: anti-virus, windows-home-server

How do I remove McAfee Antivirus from Windows Home Server?

I have been unable to find this option on the WHS Console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the [McAfee Consumer Product Removal tool](http://www.techbeta.org/tools/mcafee-consumer-products-removal-tool-mcprexe/) (MCPR.exe) removes all 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, and 2009 versions of McAfee consumer products.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on WHS, you *should* (in my own learnings) be able to use what is mentioned here: https://community.mcafee.com/thread/31852?tstart=0

**Good luck!**

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may or may not answer the question,(there are many answers at the link) it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why your solution works with detail and an easy to follow instructions.Also if you provided this info it would not run the risk of the link breaking. If you feel your answer is correct do these things and re-edit. Please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Answer (score -1):

Found it - under Add-ins